# Can Angular's Decimal Pipe Display 4 Integer Digits Without a Comma?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular's Decimal Pipe to display line numbers generated from the index of a ngFor loop.  I need to display digits up to 4 digits long (no decimals), but do not want a comma separation between the 3rd and 4th leading zero.  Can this be configured via the Decimal pipe, or do I need to write a custom pipe?

```
    <div *ngFor="let line of message; let i = index">
      <pre>{{i + 1 | number:'3.0'}}&nbsp;{{line}}</pre>
    </div>
```

I want the line to display as such:
0001  Line Text Here
0002  More Line Text
0003  Event More Text

I'm getting: 
0,001  Line Text Here
0,002  More Line Text
0,003  Event More Text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create another pipe for that

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'noComma'
})
export class NoCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(val: number): string {
    if (val != null) {
      // here we just remove the commas from value
      return val.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}

 <pre>{{i + 1 | number:'3.0-0' | noComma }}&nbsp;{{line}}</pre>
```

The other solution is having a custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lineNumber'
})
export class LineNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(val: number, leadingZeros: number = 2): string {
    if (val != null) {

      return this.pad(val, leadingZeros);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  private pad(val: number, leadingZeros) {
    const s = val.toString();
    while (s.length < (leadingZeros || 2)) {s = '0' + s;}
    return s;
  }


}


<pre>{{i + 1 | lineNumber:'4' }}&nbsp;{{line}}</pre>
```

Comment: solution 1 is quite simple and works perfectly.  Thank so much for your help!